# Starting academic textbook/survey article for the field of persuasive communication?

Tags: social-psychology, reference-request, communication, persuasion

I am quite interested in this topic and trying to find rigorous academic sources. The Wikipedia link of persuasive speech https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persuasive_speech is not relevant to this academic field.

I am not sure if the Wikipedia page of "persuasion" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persuasion is about the field of "persuasive communication". What text/article can I start to read in order to get a big picture of the organization of this field and some recent advances?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest the classic and pioneer book in the field of communication and pursuasion by Daniel H. Pink.

**To Sell Is Human: The Surprising Truth About Moving Others**

The book not only contains the basics of pursuasions but also explains in detail, why and how things work. Its a master piece!
Hope you would enjoy it.